# How could i repeatedly send messages through server socket in python?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, message

Like the title, i would like to know how to send messages repeatedly.

Is it as simple as using a "while" function?
What I'm trying to do is, when ever a client joins. I would like to have the server end, constantly send the data to the client. And if possible a way to adjust how soon i want the next message sent out.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What kind of server and socket?  You tagged with udp, but udp is stateless.  What does it mean for a cient to join?

Comment: import socket, using socket.socket 
If that helps any. I figured out how to repeatedly send the data. Thing is now, is that, i need to know how to break from the loop.  
when ever a new client joins the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> import socket, using socket.socket If that helps any. I figured out how to repeatedly send the data. Thing is now, is that, i need to know how to break from the loop. when ever a new client joins the server - Shane O

Instead of doing

```
while True:
```

Do

```
inloop = True;
while inloop:
    bla
    if(something):
        inloop = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about the [SocketServer](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html?highlight=socketserver#module-SocketServer) module, in particular the [ThreadingMixIn](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html?highlight=socketserver#asynchronous-mixins) to allow you to handle multiple clients simultaneously.  It is a Python library, and the SocketServer.py source file can be read to see how it is implemented.

Comment: Is the ThreadingMixin similar to the Select module? Because I'm trying to figure out how to keep a client updated. While, still allowing the client to update the server.

Comment: Using a ThreadingTCPServer, for example, you get a thread for each client connection.  Then you don't have to worry about when new clients join the server.  You can just implement the behavior you want on a 1:1 client/server basis.  If you want to respond to asynchronous client requests while the server is sending constant updates, you will need to use the select module for that.  Perhaps edit your question with more detail on exactly what you are trying to do and add the code you have so far?